# FutureBuilder not building

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to display my UI using FutureBuilder widget, but it does not work for some reason. Here is my code:

```
  List<ContentData> contentList = new List<ContentData>();

  Future<String> getContentsInFuture;

  Future<String> getCourseContent() async
  {
      //Get contents from server and store it in contentList

      return "success";
  }
```

```
  void initState()
  {
    getContentsInFuture = getCourseContent();

    super.initState(); 
  }
```

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<String>(
          future: getContentsInFuture,
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot)
          {
            if(snapshot.hasData)
            {
              return contentListView();
            }
            else
            {
              return SizedBox(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                width: 60,
                height: 60,
              );
            }
          }
      ),
    );
  }
```

```
ListView contentListView()
  {
    return ListView.builder(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        itemCount: contentList.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index)
        {
          return ListTile(
            title: Text(contentList[index].contentName),
          );
        }
    );
  }
```

This code works on other pages, but does not in this case. How do I use it so that my UI displays after receiving the response from the server?

Edit:

I am now receiving the error on my Debug Console:

```
E/flutter ( 7504): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_ModalScopeStatus>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _ContentSelection.initState() completed.
E/flutter ( 7504): When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of Theme.of() changes, its dependent widgets are rebuilt. If the dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a constructor or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent widget will not reflect the changes in the inherited widget.
E/flutter ( 7504): Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget build() methods. Alternatively, initialization based on inherited widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is called after initState and whenever the dependencies change thereafter.
```

Comment: It looks okay on first sight. What exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: Whats in contentListView() ?

Comment: @nvoigt `if(snapshot.hasData)` never evaluates to true

Comment: @krumpli I've edited the question to include `contentListView()`

Comment: If I use `WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) => getContentsInFuture = getCourseContent(););` it works as expected, but other pages require a refresh to show the updated data.

Comment: I tested your code on DartPad. snapshot.hasdata is returned true and snapshot.data equals success. Please check here https://dartpad.dev/65722052644360cddfbd2cd4e70d298d See the console log once Widget build is over.

Comment: I have no idea why it's not working. However, Meigara Juma's method works, but that is obviously not the best practice. Will try and figure out where exactly the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the error code I posted above, all I had to do was replace:

```
void initState()
  {
    getContentsInFuture = getCourseContent();

    super.initState(); 
  }
```

with

```
@override
  void didChangeDependencies()
  {
    super.didChangeDependencies();
    
    getContentsInFuture = getCourseContent();
  }
```